# Does appengine standard java 11 support anything similar to ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getRemainingMillis()

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-11

In java 8 appengine standard we had some methods :

1. ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getRemainingMillis()
2. SystemProperty.environment.value()

Are there any equivalent methods for Java 11 appengine standard ?

The migration guide says that appengine sdk is not supported now and these Classes were part of the sdk. I still tried with appengine-api-1.0-sdk version 1.9.77 and found that

ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getRemainingMillis() gives a Null Pointer excpetion

SystemProperty.environment.value() is null

Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 2):

For `ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getRemainingMillis()` it is the recommended method  in Java 11 runtime [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/how-requests-are-handled) so it is still supported. Just make sure of importing the package in your dependencies manager.

`SystemProperty.environment.value()` is part of the GAE java libraries as well so it is supported when imported with the dependency manager

Comment: Thankyou Jose for your reply. Do you know what the dependency is for java 11? The migration guide says that appengine sdk is not supported now and these Classes were part of the sdk. I still tried with sdk and found that 
ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getRemainingMillis() gives a Null Pointer excpetion
SystemProperty.environment.value() is null